# Can __init__() function in python be invoked at a different moment than at object creation?

Tags: python, function

Is it possible to invoke `__init__()` function explicitly? Or the function is always invoked when an object of the class is instantiated?

Comment: Technically yes, but don't.

Comment: `__init__` is invoked when a new instance of the object has been created. You can call it explicitly on instances, it is otherwise a normal method, but you generally wouldn't want to do that anyway. Why do you want to know this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__init__` is invoked on instantiation. When you call `some_instance = SomeClass(a, b)`, it is called with `self`, `a` and `b` as arguments.

Python has the "we are all consenting adults" motto, so yes, you can - but every time you call double-underscored methods you should really know what you are doing and you have to face the consequences if it breaks something.

Most classes are not designed to have `__init__` called after instantiation, and it would be an odd design; if you are tempted to call `some_instance.__init__(*args)` in order to recycle an object, just get a new instance calling `SomeClass(*args)` - calling `__init__` is not guaranteed to reset state from an existing instance, gambling on this would be bad design.

I'm not aware of any use case for calling `__init__` explicitly except for overriding the parent class `__init__` using `super`.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, `__init__` is not called whenever the object is created but instantiated. The job of object creation is of `__new__`, which is called before `__init__`, and hence `__new__` is called the constructor of a class. Please refer [`__new__`](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__) for detailed explanation. 
Coming back to question, Yes it is possible to do so. Here is the quickie to demonstrate:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "instantiating object"
... 
>>> t = Test()
instantiating object
>>> t.__init__()
instantiating object
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python is a very lenient language which also means you can do some things that you shouldn't. So while `__init__()` is a method (which means you can call it directly, like any other method), the results vary from class to class. Some classes initialized all their state in `__init__()`, so calling it again effectively resets the class. Other classes behave differently and there is no guarantee that a class will always behave in one way or the other.

Usually, this question comes up when you need a two-step init (i.e. create the class, so some setup and then really init it). Create a new `init()` method for that:

```
a = A()
a.setFoo(foo)
a.init()
```

Similarly, if your class supports reset, add a `reset()` method.